# CSS - center div with respect to document

Tags: html, css

I need to center a modal with css. I used position:fixed; top:50%; left:50%;
However, since the site has a fixed left side navigation bar, it does the positioning with respect to the main content div to the right. Can I do positioning with respect to the total browser width with css, ignoring the container div?

Comment: Post your code here of what you did so far. Better if you could create a [demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net).

Comment: I figured it out by making a wrapper around the modal and setting it's position to 0,0. Then, I used margin: 0 for the modal to center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout new simplified version with comments.

```css
#modal-overlay {
  /* stretch overlay to all screen and fix it */
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  
  /* place it higher by z-axis */
  z-index: 99999;
  
  /*align children to center with flexbox */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  /* simple styling*/
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
#modal {
  /* simple styling*/
  width: 400px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="modal-overlay">
  <div id="modal">
    Hello world!
  </div>
</div>
```

More info:

1. [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)
2. [Css positions](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/)

Comment: You need to explain what you are doing and not just hand him a fish.